# How can I know the parallele degree in the session?

Tags: sybase

I have this procedure

```
create procedure TEST_MT
AS
begin
set parallel_degree 1
select * from ttt WHERE CODE =99
END
```

how can I know what is the parallele degree in the session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the procedure after setting SET SHOWPLAN ON, and the query plan is displayed with the actual parallel degree. Note that this may potentially vary between executions since the pll level can depend on available resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of @@parallel_degree